# Is it necessary to put table name in URI? what if we have two tables in content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

i have one question regarding URI! i have two tables in my content provider! to use both table i required URI for each table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a Parent uri and table names appended for the Uri of each of the tables
for example

```
content://myapp/content
content://myapp/content/table1
content://myapp/content/table2

....
```

Comment: i think this is the only way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its better to have Uri for each table if you want to query them separately.
You can also create views with are joins on tables and query the view instead.

Comment: Ya! actually my project includes 90 tables! thats y m asking! any better way??